# what is Virtual Local clock in TSync?

Tags: time, synchronization, autosar

I am exploring the TSync in the Adaptive platform. In some places, I found `Virtual Local Time`.As per my understanding for each clock, there will reference to clock source like OsCounter or EthCounter.In the classic platform, there is one reference container `StbMLocalTimeClock` here we can refer the OsCounter or EthCounter.But In adaptive TSync what is the virtual time. How to fetch time from virtual clocks for calculating the `RateCorrection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the title of your question, from my understanding is that a virtual clock is just a variable representing the ECU-local clock. Of course you can read the clock directly from the hardware via the driver, that is fine, but when you want to synchronize your ECU to an external clock, let's say: *FlexRay*, *Ethernet*, *CAN*, etc, you cannot update the Hardware clock (read-only), that is why you need a virtual (variable) clock, where you apply the rate correction to catch-up with the ECU-external clock (global clock).
How to read the virtual clock in *StbM*, that probably will be specified in the user Manual of the *StbM* Component developer company, for example *Vector*. If you are implementing it by yourself, then it is up-to you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the classic platform, I understood the use case of virtual clocks, but In adaptive how to refer the hardware sources like OsCounter , EthCounter